# How to reference a class in a subfolder and different namespace?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a tiny app that has the following directory structure:

```
GUI
- MainWindow.cs
Model
Resources
Utilities
Program.cs
```

*MainWindow.cs* is inside GUI folder and its namespace is *OrtizOL.BackupTimer.GUI* , by other hand, Programs.cs is inside the root directory and its namepace is *OrtizOL.BackupTimer*.

*BTMainWindow.cs* file:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OrtizOL.BackupTimer.GUI
{
    public partial class BTMainWindow : Form
    {
        // code ...
    }
}
```

Program.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OrtizOL.BackupTimer.GUI;

namespace OrtiOL.BackupTimer
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Application.Run (new BTMainWindow() );
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I need to compile using this command:

```
csc /t:winexe /out:OrtizOLBackupTimer.exe /recurse:GUI *.cs
```

It doesn't work. Error message:

CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OrtizOL' could not be found (are you missing a using  directive or an assembly reference?)

Do I need to make an assembly of *BTMainWindow* first? What is correct way to reference a class in a sub-directory?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

For the code you posted you have the namespace for BTMainWindow declared as ***OrtizOL.BackupTimer***  not ***OrtizOL.BackupTimer.GUI***

Comment: With the command line compiler you will also need to do something like:  csc /t:winexe /out:NamedFile.exe /recurse:GUI\*.cs  Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct the namespace of class `BTMainWindow` from  `namespace OrtizOL.BackupTimer` to:

```
namespace OrtizOL.BackupTimer.GUI
```